# Matthew correlation coefficient for multi class scenario

Tags: correlation, multiclass-classification

I have a data set with predicted values ranging from 0 to 100 % in 10% steps and actual values ranging from 0 to 100% in 1% steps. Is it possible to calculate the Matthew correlation coefficient using such data? How would I do that? Or would I have to round the actual values to 10% steps so they "match" the predicted values?